# How to Image rotate in codeigniter after image uploading

Tags: php, codeigniter

i want to rotate image on edit mode. means can i rotate image after uploaded or get image path and rotate that image.

Below code is not working

```
        $image_id = $_GET['id'];

        $imagedata = $this->universaladmin_model->getSingleRecords('gallery',array('image_id'=>$image_id));

        $source_image = base_url(GALLERY_UPLOAD_DIRECTORY)."/". $imagedata['imagename'];


        $config['create_thumb'] = FALSE; //No thumbnail
        $config['source_image'] = $source_image; //full path for the source image
        $config['rotation_angle'] = '90';// 

        $this->load->library('image_lib',$config);

        //Rotate the image
        $this->image_lib->rotate();
```

Comment: [Here's a link to CI3's image rotate function that has example code.](http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/image_lib.html#CI_Image_lib::rotate). You didn't set `$config['image_library'] ` or call `$this->image_lib->initialize($config);`.

Comment: Also add ` echo $this->image_lib->display_errors();` to see what's not working.

Comment: "not working" two words that have almost 0 debugging potential. but @ourmandave seems to have hit the nail on the head...